# How can I disable all the submit buttons then re-enable specific ones?

Tags: jquery

I have the following script inside my asp.net mvc 3 web application to disable all the submit buttons when the user click on them to prevent successive submition for the same data:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("input[type='submit']").click(function () {
        $(this).prop('disabled', true);
    });
});
```

The above script is working fine, but disabling the submit buttons such as "search" will prevent the users from performing another search unless they refresh the page.
So I was thinking if I can modify my script to re-enable the submit button after let say 2 seconds.
I tired to use `delay()` but it did not work.

So I have the folloiwng questions :

1. Is my approach valid for defining a delay time?
2. How I can define a delay time and then re-enable the button.

Answer (score 2):

```
$("input[type='submit']").click(function () {
        var $this = $(this);
        $this.prop('disabled', true);
        setTimeout(function() {
          $this.prop('disabled', false);
        },2000);
    });
```

***[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/ad2CK/)***

Answer (score 1):

I disagree with the 2 second delay that you have decided on.  What if the call takes more than 2 seconds?  Not all of us are so lucky as to have a high-speed broadband connection. :)
Almost any *assumption* made with regard to network latency is dangerous.

A much better approach would be to use an AJAX call and utilize its callback functions to know exactly when a response is returned from the server.

> Lifted from - http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

```
$.ajax({
  url: 'ajax/test.html',
  success: function(data) {
    $('.result').html(data);
    alert('Load was performed.');
  }
});
```

---

You can try adding a specific class to all the submit buttons you want to disable.  Something like `.canDisable`, and then when you disable all the submit buttons, you can specify an additional selector to pin-point *exactly* the buttons you want to disable.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("input[type='submit']").filter(".canDisable").click(function () {
        $(this).prop('disabled', true);
    });
});
```

I'm using the `.filter()` function to filter out all of the elements that contain the `.canDisable` class.

---

References -

- `filter()` - http://api.jquery.com/filter/

> **Description:** Reduce the set of matched elements to those that match the selector...

Answer (score 0):

My idea for this problem is that you set an attribute "nodisable" on the inputs you don't want to disable and then you disable the fields like this:

`$("input[type='submit']:not([nodisable])").prop("disabled", true);`

`<input type="submit">` would be disabled, `<input type="submit" nodisable>` not.

Enabling would also work with this:
`$("input[type='submit']").prop("disabled", false);`

In combination with the ajax method i think this is the best method to solve this problem.