# how to disable a button for two seconds after click and then enable itself again?

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net

how to disable a button for two seconds after click and then enable itself again?

i want to do this in OnClientClick in javascript and after run the OnClientClick it will run OnClick event then enable button again

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10471964/how-can-i-disable-all-the-submit-buttons-then-re-enable-specific-ones

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this function:

```
//Disable the button here
setTimeout("EnableTheButton();", 2000); // put this inside the click event
```

Then declare this function:

```
function EnableTheButton() {
    // enable the button here
}
```

Answer (score 2):

To do this with in pure javascript is pretty easy:

```
var btn = document.getElementById("myButton");
btn.onclick = function() {
    btn.disabled = true; // disable button
    window.setTimeout(function() {
       btn.disabled = false; // enable button
    }, 2000 /* 2 sec */); 
}; // Warning: this will replace existing onclick event
```

If you're using [jQuery](http://jquery.com/), then you can use this code instead:

```
var btn = $("#myButton");
btn.click(function() {
    btn.attr("disabled", "disabled"); // disable button
    window.setTimeout(function() {
       btn.removeAttr("disabled"); // enable button
    }, 2000 /* 2 sec */); 
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the click even to disable the button, then set a timeout to re–enable it after the required time:

```
<button onclick="
  var button = this;
  this.disabled = true;

  // Put other listener code here

  window.setTimeout(function(){
    button.disabled = false;
  }, 2000);
">Button</button>
```

or dynamically attached:

```
window.onload = function() {

    document.getElementById('b0').onclick = function() {

      var button = this;
      button.disabled = true;

      // Put other listener code here

      window.setTimeout(function(){
        button.disabled = false;
      }, 2000);
    };
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try this:
HTML page :

```
<button id="myButon" onclick="disableButon();"></button>
```

javascript part:

```
function disableButon()
{   
    var timer;
    document.getElementById('myButon').disabled = true;
    timer = setTimeout("activateButon()", minutes * 60000);
}
```

Next function enable :

```
function activateButon()
{
    document.getElementById('myButon').disabled = false;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Please refer to below code snippet for enabling **Save** button after 10000 milliseconds (10 seconds)

You can initially set your control to disabled: true  OR OnLoad you can setDisabled(true). That is absolutely per you requirement. And then you can do the following way :

`clearTimeout(this.enableSaveButton);`

`this.enableSaveButton = setTimeout(function () {`
            `if (Ext.getCmp('btn-Save'))`
            `Ext.getCmp('btn-Save').setDisabled(false);`
        `}, 10000);`